# Pandas: using list comprehension to create a new column based on conditional values from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a Pandas dataframe df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({
    
'probability': [0.51, 0.48, 0.52, 0.71, 0.38, 0.22, 0.59, 0.70, 0.44, 0.62, 0.38],
'indicator': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    
})

df

    probability   indicator
0   0.51          1
1   0.48          0
2   0.52          0
3   0.71          1
4   0.38          0
5   0.22          1
6   0.59          0
7   0.70          1
8   0.44          0
9   0.62          1
10  0.38          0
```

I'd like to create a new column named `accuracy` that takes a value of 1 if the row-wise `probability` value is greater than 0.50 ***and*** the row-wise `indicator` is 1, otherwise a value of 0.

The desired output would look like this:

```
    probability   indicator    accuracy
0   0.51          1            1
1   0.48          0            0
2   0.52          0            0
3   0.71          1            1
4   0.38          0            0
5   0.22          1            0
6   0.59          0            0
7   0.70          1            1
8   0.44          0            0
9   0.62          1            1
10  0.38          0            0
```

I can do this using the following:

```
conditions = [
    (df['probability'] > 0.5)  & (df['indicator'] == 1),
    (df['probability'] <= 0.5) & (df['indicator'] == 1),
    (df['probability'] <= 0.5) & (df['indicator'] == 0)
]

choices = [1, 0, 0]
df['accuracy'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

But, I feel like this is 'hacky'.

As a means to streamline this, I also tried:

```
df['accuracy_1'] = np.select(condlist = [(df['probability'] > 0.5 & df['indicator'] == 1)], choicelist = [1], default=0)
```

But, this throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [int64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Is it possible to do this using list comprehension or some other more elegant approach?

Thanks!

Comment: what about simply `df['accuracy'] = (df['probability'].gt(0.5)&df['indicator'] .eq(1)).astype(int)`?

Comment: How is it hacky? It's short, very readable and a list comprehension would put all those conditions on the same line which is also less maintainable. I would stick to what you have now.

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal -- is it even possible to use list comprehension when you have more than one column?

Comment: @equanimity the error you got with your one liner is because you don't have enough parenthesis, it should be `(df['probability'] > 0.5) & (df['indicator'] == 1)` like in your first condition of the first solution

Comment: I wrote the list comprehension in my answer and you can realize it's really not the right choice :)

Answer (score 0):

`select` is not useful here as you have a binary condition. `where` is more appropriate in this case:

```
df['accuracy'] = np.where(df['probability'].gt(0.5) & df['indicator'].eq(1), 1, 0)
```

However the @Ben.T's solution for this case is perfect (`int(True)` -> 1, `int(False)` -> 0):

```
df['accuracy'] = (df['probability'].gt(0.5) & df['indicator'].eq(1)).astype(int)
```

List comprehension is probably not the right choice for 2 reasons:

- it's slow to iterate over each rows, prefer a vectorized solution
- it's not readable unlike `select` function

```
df['accuracy'] = [1 if (row.probability > 0.5 and row.indicator == 1)
                    else 0 if (row.probability <= 0.5 and row.indicator == 1)
                    else 0 if (row.probability <= 0.5 and row.indicator == 0)
                    else 0  # default like np.select
                    for row in df.itertuples()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['accuracy']=0
df.loc[(df['probability']>=0.5) & (df['indicator']==1),'accuracy']=1
```